# Heroku silex route show 404 except "/"

Tags: php, heroku, silex

This piece of code was from an example at heroku. But except the route /, anything else I add does not work. It shows 404:

> The requested URL /e was not found on this server.

```
$app->match('/', function(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig');
});

$app->match("/dump", function(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) use ($app) {
    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
})->bind("dump");
$app->get("/t", function() use ($app) {
    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
})->bind("t");
$app->get("/d", function() {
    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
})->bind("d");
$app->get("/e", function() {
    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
});
$app->run();
```

**Edit 1**
I deployed it directly on heroku server (heroku auto build on each push to master branch)

**Edit 2**
my workspace:

```
bin\worker.php
www\index.php <== the snippet is from this file
www\list.php
apache_app.conf
app.php  <== basic init, return Silex\Application $app
Procfile
```

The content of `apache_app.conf` is copied from [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#web-server-settings).
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

I figured that I need to change the apache config somehow, but I don't understand htaccess syntax.

Comment: is `/index.php/e` works? have you configured your webserver? are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: @Federkun No, none of it works. Since I deployed it on heroku server, I don't think I could config anything with it. And as far as I know, they're using apache2.

Comment: See http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/web_servers.html#apache . `/index.php/e` (where `/index.php` is your front controller) should works. When you go to `/index.php`, is it returning the index page correctly?

Comment: @Federkun `/index.php` works, `/index.php/e` show error 500.

Comment: "show error 500" is very different from "it shows 404", don't you think? What's the error message? (see your logs file)

Comment: my bad, it's a typo, I looked at a different place while typing that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apache2, you can add a .htaccess file within "/web"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and set your Procfile as:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

For nginx, create a nginx conf file with content:

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(index|index_dev)\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    internal;
}
```

and set Procfile as:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C server_conf/nginx.conf web/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just install apache :

```
composer require apache-pack
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it stumped me for weeks... to the point where I just started using / as my only route and adding other capability through passed-in variables.  Drove me up the wall.

I finally had the need to fix it for real, and after a few hours found this post:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-v5415-on-heroku-all-routes-but-not-working

TL/DR; I had duplicated a (correctly working) heroku repo to create my new one, and somewhere along the way my `web/.htaccess` file got deleted.  I replaced it, and everything works like a charm.

For me the provided test also worked well (I'm using PHP): if `eaxmple.com/ROUTE` doesn't work, but `example.com/index.php/ROUTE` ***does*** work... you have an `.htaccess` problem.

Also, for reference, here's my entire `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Hopefully this saves someone some searching...